# how do i transform this equation into the form a+bi

Tags: complex-numbers

how do can i get $(-2+i)$ e^$\pi$i/3 in the form $a+bi$ where $a$ and $b$ are in the set of real numbers $R$

any help would be greatly appreciated thank you

Answer (score 1):

HINT:

Use [Euler Formula](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/EulerFormula.html) for $\displaystyle e^{\frac{i\pi}3}$

Finally, $(a+ib)(c+id)=ac-bd+i(ad+bc)$

Comment: ahh yes thank you!